# Caminho diretorio ftp com espaços

Tags: java

Bom dia pessoal, estou com problemas para chegar a um subdiretorio no ftp, o nome de um dos subdiretorios tem espaço, e com isso não consigo avançar.
Estou fazendo um projeto em Java.
Alguém poderia ajudar por favor ?

```
ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/Premium%202.0/Executaveis/Producao");
```

neste caso quando faço a copia do caminho, é inserido o %2, então só é listado a raiz do ftp.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar utilizar a contrabarra `\` para escapar o espaço, assim como é feito ao navegar em diretórios do linux.
Faça assim:

```
ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/Premium\\ 2.0/Executaveis/Producao");
```

É preciso usar duas contrabarras pois o java utiliza a contrabarra como caracter de escape.

Comment: funcionou da seguinte forma seguindo a ideia do Andre Gusmao
`ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/Premium " + "2.0/Executaveis/Producao");`
desta forma chegou no diretorio producao e listou os arquivos dentro do mesmo.

Comment: `ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/Premium 2.0/Executaveis/Producao");`
@FabioAragão, não funciona apenas utilizando o espaço?

Comment: Não, ele dá erro no netbeans: illegal scape character e daí não salva, mas aceitando a opção do netbeans para corrigir, ele faz desta forma e dai salva e funciona listando realmente os arquivos que estão dentro deste diretorio

Comment: @FabioAragão, eu editei minha resposta, agora não vai dar erro de compilação.

Comment: não deu certo, pois o resultado é que exibe os arquivo na raiz e não no diretorio em questão